# Npm install github private repo failed

Tags: git, npm

`ssh -T git@github.com` success

`git clone git clone git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git` success

So I think I have set the right ssh key for github , but when I run

`npm install git+ssh://github.com:<username>/<repo>.git` Failed

errors are some thing like

```
Connection reset by 20.205.243.166 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Chekc what is going on with:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git
```

You will see what key is consider by the `npm install ssh` command.

In case your private key is not standard:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your private key>' npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git
```